# I wrote a pymongo script to add sample user but it is not working

Tags: python

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Debaditya:<password>@pycluster.d6kvk.gcp.mongodb.net/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
db.command("createUser", "sample", roles=["read"])
```

**Help me pls the code is given above**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for inserting a document in a collection.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Debaditya:<password>@pycluster.d6kvk.gcp.mongodb.net/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
db.students.insert_one({"name": "Test User", "rollNo": 37})
```

In above example **students** is the collection name where you have inserted the above row.

If you want to list the rows in the collection.

```
list(db.students.find())
```

Just got through the documention of pymongo [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)